# Missing constant after Laplace inverse

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I took this Cauchy problem
\begin{align}
&y''-3y'+2y=4t+8,\\
&y(0) = 2,\\
&y'(0) =7
\end{align}

And transformed it through Laplace transform
$$ Y(s)=\frac{4-8s}{s^2(s-1)(s-2)} + \frac{1+2s}{(s-1)(s-2)} $$

Simplified to
$$ Y(s) =\frac{2}{s^2} + \frac{1}{s-1} + \frac{2}{s-2} $$

Inversed back to
$$ y(t) = 2t + e^t + 2e^{2t} $$

However, the solution states that there should also be a constant of $-1$ to the function $y(t).$ I can not figure out where I lost a $1/s$ in my calculations. [Transcript here.](https://gofile.io/d/IorgLL)

Comment: What are the intial conditions ?

Comment: y(0) = 2, y'(0) = 7

Answer (score 1):

Here, $s$ has a power $2$ in the denominator(in the first fraction). So besides $\dfrac{A}{s^2}$ you've to consider another term $\dfrac{A'}{s}$.

([for reference](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/algebra/rational_expressions/partial_fractions.html))

On solving, the first fraction becomes

$\dfrac{-1}{s} + \dfrac{2}{s^2} + \dfrac{4}{s-1} - \dfrac{3}{s-2}$.

Now you have that $-1$.